# How to force compiler to use ldc.i8 IL instruction instead of ldc.i4 plus conv.i8?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

This is my C# code:

```
const long pSize = 20;
```

No matter if I use x64 or Any CPU to build it in Release mode, I get below MSIL instructions:

```
  IL_0010:  ldc.i4.s   20
  IL_0012:  conv.i8
```

However, MSIL has ldc.i8 instruction. How to make compiler to use this?

Comment: Why would you want to do what compiler is normally responsible for?

Comment: So you want to force the compiler to generate longer code than necessary?

Comment: You are asking to make the MSIL *less* efficient, ldc.i8 requires 4 more bytes.  No point to that.

Comment: @HansPassant do you mean "conv,i8" won't actually use extra bytes?

Comment: Okay, you win, it is less efficient by 3 bytes.

Comment: @HansPassant how do you observe the bytes change caused by IL in debugger?

Comment: Just keep ildasm.exe handy so you can see.  I added it to the Tools menu.

Comment: Also note that the IL is just going to be converted into executable code by the jitter, and the jitter is what is primarily responsible for optimizations.  There are plenty of optimizations that the compiler could theoretically perform, but that it leaves up to the jitter to handle as appropriate.

Comment: +1 because it was a good question that tricked Eric into educating us all on the value the C# compiler places on code size.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> MSIL has ldc.i8 instruction. How to make compiler to use this?

You don't. That would be worse code.

```
ldc.i4.s   20
conv.i8
```

is three bytes of code: two for the instructions and one for the constant.  Whereas

```
ldc.i8 20
```

is nine bytes: one for the instruction and eight for the constant.

The compiler is smart enough to avoid six unnecessary bytes. Remember, the speed of the code can be adversely affected by the number of page faults needed to load it into memory; generating code *three times larger than it needs to be* works against that goal.

But wait, there's more, and it's all bad.

The larger a basic block of code is, the more likely it is that a branch around it will be longer than fits in the compact branch instruction format. That means that this de-optimization can make branch instructions large, which in turn makes *their* basic blocks larger, and now maybe branches around *them* are not compact, and the whole thing can snowball.

It's not just the six extra bytes; it's all the consequences of those six extra bytes making *other* code bigger; you have to account for that cost as well.

The compiler is doing a good job. Let it do its work.

If your heart is set on having a compiler that generates worse code, the source code of the compiler is available. Feel free to write a de-optimizing compiler if you really need one for some reason.

Comment: What is actual effect of instruction "conv.i8" ? My C# code wants to treat 20 as ‘long’ and multiply with another long number later. I thought conv.i8 converts 20 from byte to long.

Comment: @Sheen: The opcode semantics are clearly documented; do some research. Also, I find it somewhat disturbing that you asked how to force the compiler to generate an alternative instruction sequence *without knowing what the current actual instruction sequence instructions do*. C# is designed so that you can reason about your code knowing the semantics of C#; don't worry about the IL.  The IL generated is correct.

Comment: Eric, thanks for suggestion. I read MSDN page. It says 3 steps: 
1. value is pushed onto the stack.
2. value is popped from the stack and the conversion operation is attempted.
3. If the conversion is successful, the resulting value is pushed onto the stack.

So in runtime, is it better to have int64 directly put on stack?

Comment: @Sheen: What do you mean "at runtime" and "stack"? IL is jitted! That stack is logical, not physical. And what do you mean by "better"? Better compared to what, and by what metric?