# Why does the compiler optimize ldc.i8 and not ldc.r8?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-optimization, cil

I'm wondering why this C# code

```
long b = 20;
```

is compiled to

```
ldc.i4.s 0x14
conv.i8
```

(Because it takes 3 bytes instead of the 9 required by `ldc.i8 20`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592881/how-to-force-compiler-to-use-ldc-i8-il-instruction-instead-of-ldc-i4-plus-conv-i) for more information.)

while this code

```
double a = 20;
```

is compiled to the 9-byte instruction

```
ldc.r8 20
```

instead of this 3-byte sequence

```
ldc.i4.s 0x14
conv.r8
```

(Using mono 4.8.)

Is this a missed opportunity or the cost of the `conv.i8` outbalances the gain in code size ?

Comment: Roslyn doesn't optimize this either

Comment: Your optimization isn't one, because the conversion from int to float isn't trivial, unlike the conversion from int to long. You are arguing to complicate both the compiler (which has to figure out when this sequence could be safely used) *and* the jitter (which has to recognize this sequence to produce a single optimized load), or else produce code that's incorrect or slower than what we've got now. And all to reduce IL size, which is relatively unimportant -- the size of the jitted object code matters a lot more, and there would be no reduction in this case.

Comment: (I'm essentially restating what the existing answers are already saying, but possibly slightly more direct.)

Comment: Another reason not mentioned in the answers so far: how common are longs initialized to small integer values vs doubles initialized to small integer values? I don't have a corpus of C# code in front of me right now but I would make a guess that longs are initialized to small integers more often than doubles are; even if it is an optimization -- and remember, the optimization has to be in the jitter too -- it might not be much of a win over all.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert, In the bunch of C# code I have in front of me, most of double initialized from string literals are initialized with integer values: 0, -1, 1 and 2 mostly. The value are modified afterwards obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you will get more satisfactory answer than "because noone thought it necessary to implement it."

The fact is, they could've made it this way, but as Eric Lippert has many times stated, features are chosen to be implemented rather than chosen not to be implemented. In this particular case, this feature's gain didn't outweigh the costs, e.g. additional testing, non-trivial conversion between `int` and `float`, while in the case of `ldc.i4.s`, it's not that much of a trouble. Also it's better not to bloat the jitter with more optimization rules.

As shown by the [Roslyn source code](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/614299ff83da9959fa07131c6d0ffbc58873b6ae/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/CodeGen/ILBuilderEmit.cs#L654), the conversion is done only for `long`. All in all, it's entirely possible to add this feature also for `float` or `double`, but it won't be much useful except when producing shorter CIL code (useful when inlining is needed), and when you want to use a float constant, you usually actually use a floating point number (i.e. not an integer).

Comment: Even if inlining doesn't happen at the IL level (where it's quite tricky and rarely useful - calls are usually cheaper than inlining in IL), it happens in the JITter. And on my computer, both IL sources produce the exact same assembly code - load a floating point value from the data segment, a single load instruction. Needless to say, it's heavily inlined, since it's just a constant.

Comment: @Luaan You are correct that inlining happens at the JITter level, but I haven't disputed that. In order for a method (without *AggresiveInlining*) to be considered a candidate for inlining, it has to have at most a certain number of instructions. That's what I meant.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. The only thing that matters size-wise is the produced assembly code - which has little to do with the original IL code size (again, as evidenced by these two snippets which have vastly different IL size while producing the exact same assembly). But I'm pretty sure those are just implementation details anyway, though I'm not in the mood to go spec digging right now :) IL code size has a pretty low cost, all in all.

Comment: @Luaan Going to cite [MSDN Blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidnotario/2004/11/01/jit-optimizations-inlining-ii/) - "*Size of inlinee is limited to 32 bytes of IL*". That's what I meant, even though I didn't specify the exact number. Yes, the size of the assembly code is important when you run the code, but the size of the IL being in a limit matters when you want your method to be inlined at all; just this heuristic (and some other criteria). Don't worry, I even proved Hans Passant wrong on that. ☺

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting. Still an implementation detail, but quite important. Though I'd guess that in practice you run into the other inlining limitations long before your IL gets to 32 bytes. And note that this is from 2004 - the limitations might be quite different now, since we've had a few new better and faster JITters in the meantime. I don't really care enough to try, though - it really is something I mostly care about on a case-by-case basis (usually as a result of profiling), rather than in general. I don't write a lot of tight loops with method calls in C# :)

Answer (score 7):

Because float is not a smaller double, and integer is not a float (or vice versa).

All `int` values have a 1:1 mapping on a `long` value. The same simply isn't true for `float` and `double` - floating point operations are tricky that way. Not to mention that int-float conversions aren't free - unlike pushing a 1 byte value on the stack / in a register; look at the x86-64 code produced by both approaches, not just the IL code. Size of the IL code is not the only factor to consider in optimisation.

This is in contrast to `decimal`, which is actually a base-10 decimal number, rather than a base-2 decimal floating point number. There `20M` maps perfectly to `20` and vice versa, so the compiler is free to emit this:

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_0002:  newobj      System.Decimal..ctor
```

The same approach simply isn't safe (or cheap!) for binary floating point numbers.

You might think that the two approaches are necessarily safe, because it doesn't really matter whether we do a conversion from an integer literal ("a string") to a double value in compile-time, or whether we do it in IL. But this simply isn't the case, as a bit of specification diving unveils:

ECMA CLR spec, III.1.1.1:

> Storage locations for floating-point numbers (statics, array elements, and fields of classes) are of fixed size. The supported storage sizes are float32 and float64.
>   Everywhere else (on the evaluation stack, as arguments, as return types, and as local variables) floating-point numbers are represented using an internal floating-point type. In each such instance, the nominal type of the variable or expression is either float32 or float64, but its value might be represented internally with additional range and/or precision.

To keep things short, let's pretend float64 actually uses 4 binary digits, while the implementation defined floating type (F) uses 5 binary digits. We want to convert an integer literal that happens to have a binary representation that's more than four digits. Now compare how it's going to behave:

```
ldc.r8 0.1011E2 ; expanded to 0.10110E2
ldc.r8 0.1E2
mul             ; 0.10110E2 * 0.10000E2 == 0.10110E3
```

`conv.r8` converts to the F, not float64. So we actually get:

```
ldc.i4.s theSameLiteral
conv.r8 ; converted to 0.10111E2
mul     ; 0.10111E2 * 0.10000E2 == 0.10111E3
```

Oops :)

Now, I'm pretty sure this isn't going to happen with an integer in the range of 0-255 on any reasonable platform. But since we're coding against the CLR specification, we can't make that assumption. The JIT compiler can, but that's too late. The language compiler may define the two to be equivalent, but the C# specification doesn't - a `double` local is considered a float64, not F. You can make your own language, if you so desire.

In any case, IL generators don't really optimise much. That's left to JIT compilation for the most part. If you want an optimised C#-IL compiler, write one - I doubt there's enough benefit to warrant the effort, especially if your only goal is to make the IL code smaller. Most IL binaries are already quite a bit smaller than the equivalent native code.

As for the actual code that runs, on my machine, both approaches result in exactly the same x86-64 assembly - load a double precision value from the data segment. The JIT can easily make this optimisation, since it knows what architecture the code is actually running on.

Comment: checking if double is an integer is as trivial as `d %1 == 0`, I don't see a big difference with the optimization for loading longs the check is `l < 256`...

Comment: oops, sorry for the confusion, I typed i8 instead of r8 in the original question. Fixed

Comment: the issue of runtime cost of converting and int to double IS what my real question is about. because the 2 IL posted in the question (ldc.r8 and ldc.i4 + conv.r8) produces the same value on the stack. I have notions on how floating point numbers work, but thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: I'm not confusing byte code for stack., and not assuming `conv.r8` is free. The question, at the bottom of the post is "Is this a missed opportunity, or the cost of the conv.i8 outbalance the gain in the code size ?".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130205/discussion-between-stephane-delcroix-and-luaan).

Comment: "Now, I'm pretty sure this isn't going to happen with an integer in the range of 0-255 on any reasonable platform. But since we're coding against the CLR specification, we can't make that assumption." -- We can if the integer can be exactly represented with the minimal range and precision required by the CLR, can't we? Then, even if the machine representation has more bits, those bits are guaranteed to simply be zero.

Comment: @Luaan Most of that comment is not relevant to mine. I specifically addressed the part where you talked about integers in the range 0-255. For the rest, you appear to be vastly underestimating how much the CLR requires of floating point types. Your quote mentions float32 and float64. These are the fairly well-known IEEE 754 / IEC 60559 32-bit and 64-bit floating point types. Yes, they *are* required to be implemented as positional numbers. Yes, they *are* required to have a minimal exact precision and range. This comes from the CLR spec. It does care. No hazardous guesses needed. See I.12.1.3.

Comment: @Luaan F must have an equal or greater range than float32/float64. F must have an equal or greater precision than float32/float64. F must otherwise behave as specified by IEEE 754 / IEC 60559. This is spelt out in I.12.1.3. It cannot be a decimal floating point type, like you suggested. It cannot be an entirely different numerical system like you suggested. No, I'm not confusing float32/float64 and F, the requirements for F are based on the requirements from float32/float64.

Comment: @Luaan If they cannot represent all the values of float32/float64 with enough precision to convert them back to the *exact same* original float32/float64 value, they're not valid, that'd violate the requirement (again, I.12.1.3) that "Conversions to and from the internal representation shall preserve value." If they do have enough precision for that, for all values, then sure, but that makes them examples that are irrelevant to the point you were trying to make.

Comment: @Luaan I'd try to counter that directly, but I now realise I missed something simpler: even if the float64->F conversion were allowed to be lossy, even if the result converted back to float64 could be different, even then that wouldn't make any difference, that still wouldn't make the operation unsafe: when the compile-time int->float64 conversion is exact, the run-time int->F and the run-time float64->F conversions must give the same result, because both only have a single operation, the rounding of that operation doesn't depend on whether the source was an int or a float64.

Comment: @Luaan In my previous comment, I pointed out that the load through int and the load through float64 produce the same F value, so what operations then get performed on it doesn't matter. Or are you saying that the compiler/runtime is still allowed to arbitrarily perform operations in float64 when its own internal precision is actually F? I don't see that permission in the spec. III.1.1.1 requires widening to F when values get loaded, so the multiplication always takes place on two F values. As for the effort, I never disputed that part.

Comment: @hvd The difference is that when you load a double constant, you get double precision, then you widen that to F (so it's "truncated"). When you load an int constant, you get F directly, which means you have more precision than before. But I don't think there's any point in continuing this, it's not that you're wrong - the argument I'm making really doesn't apply to integers that are small enough to fit into a double on modern architectures, and the "very different F" argument is only about the optimisation technically not being legal until you actually know the architecture you're running.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, if the int->float conversion is inexact, and the float->F is also allowed to be inexact (I'm not saying that's allowed, I'm just agreeing with you not to continue that discussion), then I do agree that changing int->float->F to int->F could change the results. And although all int32 values can be stored exactly in float64 (correct me if I'm wrong), they cannot all be stored exactly in float32, so the compiler would still need logic to only make the transformation when it's safe. (BTW, this whole same argument could perhaps also be made for shortening ldc.r8 to ldc.r4.)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's consider correctness. The `ldc.i4.s` can handle integers between -128 to 127, all of which can be exactly represented in `float32`. However, the CIL uses an internal floating-point type called `F` for some storage locations. The ECMA-335 standard says in III.1.1.1:

> ...the nominal type of the variable or expression is either `float32` or
>   `float64`...The internal representation shall have the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - The internal representation shall have precision and range greater than or equal to the nominal type.
> - Conversions to and from the internal representation shall preserve value.

This all means that any `float32` value is guaranteed to be safely represented in `F` no matter what `F` is.

We conclude that the alternative sequence of instructions that you have proposed is correct. Now the question is: is it better in terms of performance?

To answer this question, let's see what the JIT compiler does when it sees both code sequences. When using `ldc.r8 20`, the answer given in the link you referenced explains nicely the ramifications of using long instructions.

Let's consider the 3-byte sequence:

```
ldc.i4.s 0x14
conv.r8
```

We can make an assumption here that is reasonable for any optimizing JIT compiler. We'll assume that the JIT is capable of recognizing such sequence of instructions so that the two instructions can be compiled together. The compiler is given the value 0x14 represented in the two's complement format and have to convert it to the `float32` format (which is always safe as discussed above). On relatively modern architectures, this can be done extremely efficiently. This tiny overhead is part of the JIT time and therefore is incurred only once. The quality of the generated native code is the same for both IL sequences.

So the 9-byte sequence has a size issue which could incur any amount of overhead from nothing to more (assuming that we use it everywhere) and the 3-byte sequence has the one-time tiny conversion overhead. Which one is better? Well, somebody has to do some scientifically-sound experimentation to measure the difference in performance to answer that question. I would like to stress that you should not care about this unless you are an engineer or researcher in compiler optimizations. Otherwise, you should be optimizing your code at a higher level (at the source code level).